# Android GridView duplicates items Parse SDK

Tags: android, gridview, parse-platform, cursor

I'm calling a query to fetch some objects in my android app with Parse SDK and everything works fine except for the GridView which duplicates the first items after scrolling down to get the objects that are after the 2nd one and doesn't even get the right images from the 2nd item on, as shown here:

[image]

[image]

Here's my code:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {


/* Variables */
List<ParseObject> eventsArray = null;
Cursor cursor;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    super.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // Set Title on the ActionBar
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Events");

    // Call query
    queryEvents();
}



// MARK: - QUERY EVENTS
public  void queryEvents() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Configs.EVENTS_CLASS_NAME);
    query.whereEqualTo(Configs.EVENTS_IS_PENDING, false);
    query.orderByDescending(Configs.EVENTS_END_DATE);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException error) {
            if (error == null) {
                eventsArray = objects;


                // CUSTOM GRID ADAPTER
                class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                    private Cursor cursor;
                    private Context context;

                    public GridAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> objects, Cursor cursor) {
                        super();
                        this.context = context;
                        if (cursor != null)  {
                            cursor.moveToFirst();
                            this.cursor = cursor;
                        }
                    }


                    // CONFIGURE CELL
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View gridView;

                        if (convertView == null) {
                            gridView = new View(context);
                            // Inflate event_cell.xml
                            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_cell, null);

                            // Get Parse object
                            ParseObject eventObj = eventsArray.get(position);



                            // Get Title
                            TextView titleTxt = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
                            titleTxt.setText(eventObj.getString(Configs.EVENTS_TITLE).toString().toUpperCase());

                            // Get Address
                            TextView addTxt = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.addressTxt);
                            addTxt.setText(eventObj.getString(Configs.EVENTS_LOCATION).toString());

                            // Get Start & End dates
                            TextView dateTxt = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.dateTxt);
                            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy | hh:mm a");
                            dateTxt.setText(dateFormat.format(startDate).toUpperCase() + " - " + dateFormat.format(endDate).toUpperCase());


                            // Get Image
                            ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile)eventObj.get(Configs.EVENTS_IMAGE);
                            fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException error) {
                                    if (error == null) {
                                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                                        if (bmp != null) {
                                            ImageView eventImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
                                            eventImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                                        }
                                    }}});



                        } else { gridView = convertView; }

                        return gridView;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getCount() { return eventsArray.size(); }

                    @Override
                    public Object getItem(int position) { return eventsArray.get(position); }

                    @Override
                    public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

                }



                // Init GridView and set its adapter
                GridView eventsGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.eventsGridView);
                eventsGrid.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(Home.this, eventsArray, cursor));

                eventsGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        ParseObject eventObj = eventsArray.get(position);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), eventObj.getString(Configs.EVENTS_TITLE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // GO TO EventDetails activity
                    }
                });


                // Error in query
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

}

Am I doing something wrong with the **Cursor**, or maybe I don't need it?
What should I try to fix such issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Dumb question but did you check the results you get back  for duplicates?

Comment: Yes, if you tap on each cell it shows a toast message which shows the correct record based on the cell's position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getView` is wrong.

You only format the view (with title etc...) if its a new view `convertView == null` instead of inflating it only when `convertView == null`and setting it always.
Plus there is no need for `gridView`.
try this:

```
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    if (convertView == null) {
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        // Inflate event_cell.xml
                        convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_cell, null);
                    }
                    // Get Parse object
                    ParseObject eventObj = eventsArray.get(position);



                    // Get Title
                    TextView titleTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
                    titleTxt.setText(eventObj.getString(Configs.EVENTS_TITLE).toString().toUpperCase());

                    // Get Address
                    TextView addTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addressTxt);
                    addTxt.setText(eventObj.getString(Configs.EVENTS_LOCATION).toString());

                    // Get Start & End dates
                    TextView dateTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTxt);
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy | hh:mm a");
                    dateTxt.setText(dateFormat.format(startDate).toUpperCase() + " - " + dateFormat.format(endDate).toUpperCase());

                     final ImageView eventImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
                    // Get Image
                    ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile)eventObj.get(Configs.EVENTS_IMAGE);
                    fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException error) {
                            if (error == null) {
                                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                                if (bmp != null) {
                                    eventImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                                }
                            }}});
                    return convertView;
                }
```

By the way, you should divide getView to methods, like `setViewTitle`, `setViewImage`...

Its hard to read like that and will be hard for you or some else who might work on this code, to maintain it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, although you still used gridView.findViewById, I think I must change it into convertView, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll edit it but yes, replace gridview for convertview everywhere.

Comment: perfect, it's working , besides the messing up that it does with images, it loads them badly if i scroll up and down, it duplicates the first image on scroll from bottom to top on all cells :(

Comment: This line seems suspicious:
ImageView eventImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
Shouldnt it be:
ImageView eventImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
?

Comment: tried it, but it gives me this error: Error:(212, 84) error: local variable convertView is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Comment: Edited my answer (the Get Image part), try it please.

Comment: YOU'VE SAVED MY DAY! Glad I've gave you 50 points from my rep! thanks so much again!

Comment: If i could make one last question, do you know how to pass a ParseObject from Home to another activity? I'm trying this: Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, EventDetails.class);
                            i.putExtra("eventObj", eventsArray[position]); | but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Is EventDetails an Activity?
Do you want to start an Activity with this Intent or just send the object?

Comment: Yes, I want to start the EventDetails acitivity and get the ParseObject in there, then i'll make the necessary views gets, actually this is my correct code:   |  ParseObject eventObj = eventsArray.get(position);

                            // GO TO EventDetails activity
                            Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, EventDetails.class);
                            i.putExtra("eventObj", eventObj[position]);

Comment: you are missing `startActivity(i)` after you create the intent and set its extras

Comment: No, it was there, i just havent' posted the whole code :) can we chat here on stackoverflow, real quick?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114331/discussion-between-fvimagination-and-tomer-z).